# C - Reading Till The EOF, Getting Additional Addresses and Numbers (Array)

Tags: c, arrays, file, limit

So, I have a File full of numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

The case is, I don't know the exact number of numbers in this file, so I don't know the exact size of array I will need to write this file info in to this array.

I just gave array much bigger size than I need and I will show you the output, partially it does its job.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 30

int main(void){
FILE *fp;
int array[ARR_SIZE];
fp = fopen("C:/project/project.txt", "r");

printf("Numbers: ");

for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i]);
}
for(int j = 0; j < ARR_SIZE; j++){
    printf("\n%d", array[j]);
}

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to do standard things, opening file, reading file with for loop, writing all this info to array and outputting array.

Here is the output I get, I understand it is because of the size, but can you tell me how to limit all of these? Easiest way?

Output:

```
Numbers:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
4199136
0
4200896
6422240
6422296
6422476
1998244384
592257989
-2
1998220218
1998220461
4200896
6422368
4200987
4200896
```

I have array size 30 and numbers in the file 15, first 15 is okay, it is exactly what I need, but I don't need those number after it...

Comment: Count the number of succesfull lines read (check `fscanf` return value) and print only those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a stop-condition for the loop that reads from the file. One option is to stop when you can't scan an item. Use the return value from `fscanf` to detect that.

When you do the printing only print the number of items actual scan'ed.

Try

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++){
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &array[i]) != 1) break; // Stop if the scan fails
}
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){  // ARR_SIZE replaced by i
    printf("\n%d", array[j]);  
}
```

BTW: You should check that `fp` is valid just after the file open.